# I request being able to give bonuses to answerers using my credits, if they have outstanding answers

Tags: feature-request

It would be nice to be able to spend your credits rewarding those who go above and beyond answering questions, or to reward runners-up to the best answer.  I've had some amazingly helpful people tell me the answer to my questions and at the same time tell me that the question itself had flawed suppositions.  This ought to be rewarded somehow, I appreciate it greatly, as I'm sure we all do.  It's precisely the point of StackExchange.

Comment: It sounds like "bounties" might be what you're looking for

Comment: I like bounties, but this is more of a request to do such bonus granting ad hoc.

Comment: Sounds like something you should propose on [meta.stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). No one here is in a position to create features of the magnitude you request, unfortunately. We can move it there for you, if you'd like.

Comment: Please.  I will use that site next time.  And thank you.

Comment: I don't see why this question was closed. It is a perfectly valid meta question (similar questions are asked also at other meta sites without being closed), and the perfect answer is that the requested functionality is already there as part of the "bounties" feature (and some people at m.se use it exactly in that way).

Answer (score 1):

If you have at least 75 reputation points you can place a bounty on any question that was asked at least 48 hours ago.

Documentation: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties